# How to add yahoo mail account to outlook 2013?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, yahoo-mail

I was able to sync Hotmail and Gmail accounts to Outlook 2013, But Yahoo! is giving me trouble.

Kindly guide how to add Yahoo! account to Outlook 2013.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Start by adding a new account from the backstage tab.
2. Select **Manually configure server settings or additional server types** and click **Next**.
3. Select **Internet E-mail** and click **Next**.
4. Enter your account details and the [server settings](http://help.yahoo.com/kb/index?page=content&y=PROD_MAIL_MOBILE&locale=en_US&id=SLN3361) as shown below.

   [image]
5. Open the dialog **Internet E-mail Settings** by clicking **More Settings...** and switch to the **Advanced** tab.

   Set the ports as shown below and make sure the encryption is set to **SSL** for both the incoming and outgoing connection.

   [image]
6. On the **Outgoing Server** tab, make sure **My outgoing server (SMTP) requires authentication** is checked. Leave the selection on **Use same settings as my incoming mail server**.

   [image]
7. Close the dialog and click **Next** in the account creation wizard. The settings should test successfully and your account should be created.